# MySQL order INT but 0 goes last

Tags: mysql

Can I perform a query to order by an INT in ASC order but put any records with 0 last?

e.g.

1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 100, 0

Rather than

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 100

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table order by if(your_field=0,1,0),your_field
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT IF(row>0, row, 100000) as sort_row ...... ORDER BY sort_row ASC`

OR use UNION

Comment: not working, by above query the row which have 0 will not returned

Comment: Nothing in this query can affected WHAT will return, only in which order :)